# SwiftUI: Disable button selection if scrolling within ScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, scrollview, swiftui, gesture

I'm in a pickle with SwiftUI to where I have a vertical ScrollView consisting of buttons stacked vertically. When I start scrolling, there's two outcomes:

1. If I started scrolling when my finger was on the button, when the scroll stops, the button action fires.
2. If I started scrolling when my finger was on the padding between the buttons, when the scroll stops, not action occurs.

My question: is there any way to prevent the button action from firing in scenario (1.) above so i.e. the button is disabled or the action is only allowed to fire when the scroll is stopped/motionless?

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {

    ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { i in

        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {

            Button(action: {
                print("selected")
            }) {
                Text("Button \(i)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried tagging the `.gesture()` after the code block, but it only recognizes `DragGesture().onChanged()` and not `DragGesture().onEnded()`. I've considered trying to detect the location of the drag start and cross-reference that point with the position of all button on the screen, but that seems a little excessive.

Any help, suggestions, or alternatives are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use view instead of a Button. With tap gesture and (maybe) gesture mask.

Comment: Could you please add in few lines of code as well, to support your answer?

Comment: @RohitNimmala, I think @orlangur meant something like ```Text("Button \(i)).onTapGesture{ print("selected") }``` instead of ```Button(action: {...}) { Text(...)}```

Comment: Great solution! I should've considered that, but you'd think you'd want to use a Button for it's intended purpose you know...

Comment: What about if I am using NavigationLink instead of a Button, it is triggered when scrolling when it shouldn’t. Thanks!

Comment: @jberlana NavigationLink seem working fine without any additional adjustments. I tried this code: https://twitter.com/sergeygarazha/status/1258712441623580673?s=20

Comment: I have a "kind of" grid with a HStack inside a ForEach inside a Scrollview, each "cell" is a NavigationLink, and when i scroll the one with the finger on top get trigered.

Comment: @jberlana post whole code here, please. We need to check that case specifically.